# Journey Builder - Perzonalize Mobile Connect SMS with entry data

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobileconnect

In order to personalize our SMS - Journey Builder send, we need to use the values of the fields of the Data Extension that trigger de Journey Builder. This is perfectly possible with an email send, but the same `AMPScript functions` do no seem to work with the SMS. The only personalization string seems to be the `MOBILE_NUMBER`. Thank you

Comment: Yes, this should be possible, however there are some AMPscript functions that are reserved for email and don't work in SMS. Please can you provide an example of the AMPscript code that you are using in your mobile message.

Comment: Hi Eliot, for instance we have something like this where we are referring to the entry event Data Extension. While this code works in the email activity, it does not in the sms activity.

`code`%%[ 
SET @idSubscriber = _subscriberkey 
SET @rows = LookupRows("DE","CustomerID",@idSubscriber) 
SET @RowCount = RowCount(@rows) 
IF Rowcount > 0 THEN 
set @row = row(@rows,1)
set @coupon = field(@row,"Coupon") 
ENDIF 
]%%
%%=v(@coupon)=%%
`code`

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code example that you provide in your comment uses the `_subscriberkey` personalization string, which specifically relates to an email Subscriber in the All Subscribers list. MobileConnect uses it's own list model.

There are two personalization strings available for mobile messages; `MOBILE_NUMBER` and `SHORT_CODE`. Also, there are some [AMPscript variables for mobile messages](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_variables_for_use_with_mobile_messages/) that can also be used in mobile messages.

Comment: Hi Eliot, ok I understand. So no way to directly use the entry event Data Extension, unless you use a LOOKUP function. This may prove to be complicated when the mobile number is not unique KEY in the entry event (instead if you could just use the ).
Thanks

Comment: Yes, indeed. While you can use [personalization strings in Send Email Activities](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/resources/release_notes/november_2014_release/#JBEmail) using fields from the Event Source Columns in Data Extension, sadly this does not appear to apply to Send SMS Activities (I've tried). This is unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

The 2016 response from Eliot Harper is now outdated.

Currently you can insert very simple AMPscript snippets into your message to insert subscriber-specific data into your SMS. The format is `%%=v(FieldName)=%%` where "FieldName" is the name of a column (field) in the Data Extension you are using for your Journey's Entry Source.

Example full text of a personalized message:

`Hello %%=v(FirstName)=%%, here's your confirmation message.`